# How can I grep with color in Mac OS X's terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, grep, console

I recently found that on Mac OS X I can set this up in my shell `~/.profile` so that when I use `grep` it will print the matches in color (white one red).

```
alias grep='GREP_COLOR="1;37;41" LANG=C grep --color=auto'
```

But setting up an alias seems like kind of a hack way to do this. Previously I had tried with no luck:

```
export GREP_COLOR=always           # works fine in Linux
```

And then I also tried:

```
export GREP_COLOR="1;37;41"
```

Is there a better way to do this than setting up an alias?

Comment: I don't see the point of your question. An alias is how you do this. That's what it's for. `export` the environment variable e.g. in `.bash_profile`, and define `alias grep='grep --color'`, and you're done.

Comment: check this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34790/grep-color-on-mac

Comment: tl/dr: just do this instead: `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Per [Grep_color on mac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34790/grep-color-on-mac) as suggested by @lupincho, this seems to work fine and does not use an alias:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
export GREP_COLOR='1;35;40'
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Did you restart your terminal ?

Comment: Have a +1 for this as a good solution, however setting GREP_OPTIONS leads to `grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script`. Something like this is now preferred: `alias grep="\`which grep\` --color=always"`

Comment: @joelittlejohn doesn't work when using grep in pipes with xargs, eg: `find /usr/share -name '*.txt' |xargs grep testing`

Comment: @joelittlejohn's comment makes this a non-starter for me; it prints that warning on every grep command (so, many, many times on a find operation).

Comment: @rfabbri I guess that's one to take up with the grep team who deprecated this :)

Comment: For some reason for me I did not see an effect after I opened a new terminal, but `source ~/.bashrc` did it.

Comment: `--color=always`is dangerous. Scripts run from the shell will also inherit the option and cause very mysterious failures when grep starts injecting color codes to output inside scripts. `--color=auto` doesn't cause this problem.

Comment: @joelittlejohn that is not true for the default grep in OSX. Even on High Sierra 10.13, it uses FREEBSD grep 2.5.1 which HAS NOT depreciated GREP_OPTIONS. That's only true in gnu/grep

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Catalina with grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD I use the --colour argument when calling grep to activate highlighting.

> grep --colour thon /usr/share/dict/words

I found this option when I ran 'man grep' after finding this thread. It seems odd the spelling of the argument is '--colour', and not '--color'. This command prints the results with text highlighted in red.