# Grep in Mac OS X's terminal -- only displaying one color

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, colors, grep

I am used to `grep` being able to color the filename, the line number, and the match itself. These three ought to be different colors. This works flawlessly on a Linux terminal and even MinGW on Windows, but on OS X even if I set `GREP_COLOR` I can only get color on the matched result.

Is the version of `grep` packaged with the OS too old?

10.7.3 on MBA 13" with Terminal.app.

Comment: This still work? --> http://superuser.com/questions/416835/how-can-i-grep-with-color-in-mac-os-xs-terminal

Comment: I just came from there. I did exactly what was described. Just one color got set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Ignacio already said, OS X grep is a bit outdated (it's version 2.5.1). You can install the latest GNU grep though.

As always, you can install most missing Linux tools on OS X through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install grep
```

This will install `ggrep` so as not to override your existing `grep`. If you want to change that, see the info message:

> All commands have been installed with the prefix "g".
> If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
>
> ```
> PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```

Further, you can enable a color option and exclude some directories by default, which may make it more useful:

```
alias grep="ggrep --color=auto --exclude-dir={.bzr,CVS,.git,.hg,.svn,.idea,.tox}"
```

Add this to your `~/.bash_profile` or whatever shell configuration you are using.

Comment: What's a nice way to get grep to run from the new location? an alias?

Comment: @StevenLu, you may want to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`. e.g., you can do this globally by editing `/etc/paths`, or have your shell startup script (e.g., `~/.bash_profile`) edit `PATH` to change the order.

Comment: @StevenLu, see [Amending PATH so that /usr/local/bin is ahead of /usr/bin](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/49389/6883).

Comment: getting `Error: Invalid tap name 'homebrew/dupes/'` and `Error: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.`

Comment: @mustafa Thanks for the note. I fixed the answer.

Comment: And use the `--color=auto` option in GNU grep

Answer (score 1):

Correct. Multiple colors were first supported in GNU grep 2.5.3.