# macOS terminal: show filename with colors when using grep

Tags: macos, ubuntu, bash, terminal, grep

When using Ubuntu I get these colors when using grep (`grep -r "MSP" .`):

[image]

I want the same result when using macOS Monterey. I tried to add

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
```

to my bash profile and I get only colors in the search term:

[image]

How can I add the colors like in the Ubuntu case, where the filenames are also colored?

Comment: The BSD grep implementation differs from the GNU one. Have a look at this port: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228322/how-to-grep-with-filename-highlighted-in-one-color-and-the-match-highlighted-in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grep in Mac OS X's terminal -- only displaying one color](https://superuser.com/questions/419467/grep-in-mac-os-xs-terminal-only-displaying-one-color)

Comment: Thanks, but still not working.